# Excel VBA Sorting Sections

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort the below in Excel via each section then the rate. Afterwards, I would like to autosum each section and rate. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*ORIGINAL RAW DATA:*

```
Description       Amt            Section    Rate
 B 3 May        $ (2,317,143.00)    B        3
 A 3 ½  May     $   (429,783.00)    A        3 1/2
 B stuff1 3     $      1,492.00     B        3
 A stuff 3 ½    $    169,569.00     A        3 1/2
 C 3 ½ May      $(31,037,179.00)    C        3 1/2
 C stuff1 3 ½   $    217,288.00     C        3 1/2
 A 3 ½ Jun      $  2,000,000.00     A        3 1/2
 B stuff2 3     $    528,207.00     B        3    
 B stuff3 3     $  1,867,888.00     B        3
```

*DESIRED OUTPUT:*

```
Description       Amt
 A 3 ½  May     $   (429,783.00)
 A 3 ½ Jun      $  2,000,000.00 
 A stuff 3 ½    $    169,569.00 
                $  1,739,786.00 
 B 3 May        $ (2,317,143.00)
 B stuff1 3     $      1,492.00 
 B stuff2 3     $    528,207.00 
 B stuff3 3     $  1,867,888.00 
                $     80,444.00 
 C 3 ½ May      $(31,037,179.00)
 C stuff1 3 ½   $    217,288.00 
                $(30,819,891.00)
```

Comment: What code have you tried? We are here to help you with problems in your code, not write all the code for you.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you can record a macro to get yourself started. Just turn on the recorder and do it manually and it will give you code.

Comment: Use a PivotTable. Best, easiest solution there is. Millions of examples on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry as I should've copied the basic VBA code that I currently have. Is there a good method in autosumming the different sections without using a pivot table?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "D2:D56"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "E2:E56"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:F56")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```